# Access POP3 content from other computer

Tags: email, remote-access, imap, pop3

I have a tough mission, that I have no idea how to accompish it.
In our company, all the e-mail accounts are configured as IMAP accounts, therefore we can access the e-mail from wherever. However, there are 2 e-mail accounts configured as POP3 account.
I REALLY have to make it possible for one of these two accounts to access all the e-mail content from home. We do not have remote access (neither a way to do it right now). How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no way to do this. With POP3 the mail are downloaded to the client machine and *removed from the server*. So if one client was downloaded mail, other client won't find on the server them anymore.

This removal could be offset by some time, mail clients often do have settings like "remove mail from server after N days". If you set that N high enough on ALL clients that access this mailbox and also guarantee that each client accesses the mailbox at least once per N days, your all clients will have all mail. Otherwise, some mails will not reach some clients.

If you disable removal completely, your mailbox will grow, and even if you have sufficient space to store mail, that will slow down mail processing for this mailbox, because POP3 wasn't designed to sync huge count of mails.

Or, you may go completely different route, configure only one client on some computer and give access to that computer via e.g. RDP.

The best is to consider this need as a proper requirement to cease with POP3 and employ IMAP for this mailbox.

Comment: The RDP option is the first and most obvious solution, thing is this specific PC there is no way that is possible. My idea would be something like saving the content of that locally saved e-mail account in some virtual server of some kind, and make that accessible from outside the company. But I have no idea on how to do this

Comment: Don't seek obscure problematic ways. Don't fight for POP3. It isn't worth it. Cross the stream where it is shallowest. Implement proper solutions, designed for your task. Use IMAP, your situation requires it.